# CSS multiple outlines with negative outline-offset

Tags: html, css

I got  with image as a background, and want to get effect of multiple inner outlines.
Outlines should be solid white 2px, but in different position - say -4px, -8px, -12px.
Goal is to get more than 2 outlines.

I know i can make box-shadow and outline to get double outilne, but noticed that i cannot attach to div 3 classes with different outline-offset - div have applied only last of class.

My code:

```
<div class="imgfield effect1 effect2 effect3"> </div>
```

and example css:

```
.imgfield { background: url(someimage.jpg); ... width, height etc. }
.effect1 { outline: yellow 2px solid; outline-offset: -4px; }
.effect2 { outline: red 2px solid; outline-offset: -8px; }
.effect3 { outline: blue 2px solid; outline-offset: -12px; }
```

In this example there will be only blue inner outline but now red niether yellow. How to workaround this?

-----------edit-----------------

All answers are good. I must admit i try handling `after` and `before` but i'm not enough familiar with it. `Box-sizing: border-box` was also important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to complete @Mr.Alien demo/answer , i would use border's pseudo for a better compatibility.

```
    .effect {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        outline: 1px solid #000;
        position:relative;/* pick as reference for pseudo absolute */
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* keep box within size given */
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
/* size pseudo within from coordonates */
    .effect:before {
        content:"";
        top:2px;
        left:2px;
        right:2px;
        bottom:2px;
        border: green 2px solid;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .effect:after {
        content:"";
        top:6px;
        left:6px;
        right:6px;
        bottom:6px;
        border: red 2px solid;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8etS9/1/)**

Comment: does not work if border is not standard shape

Comment: @PuiHoLam this a quiet old Q/A , do you have an example of *not a standard shape* so i can see what we could do :)

Comment: No I'm implementing a generic vue component where the outline should adapt to any shape of QBtn of the quasar framework.

Answer (score 1):

How about using pseudo elements for this? Here, I am using a single `class` with a single element, but am positioning the pseudo elements i.e `:before` and `:after` using `position: absolute;`.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8etS9/)</kbd>

You can surely play with `z-index` if you have any issue with the element overlapping.

```
.effect {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}

.effect:before {
    content: "";
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: green 2px solid; 
    outline-offset: -4px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.effect:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: red 2px solid; 
    outline-offset: -8px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: for a better compatibility, pseudo element should be scaled down and border used instead outline. outline-offset is not widely supported :)

Comment: @GCyrillus ummm yea even borders are fine if the element is positioned absolute :) but again, we will have to use, top left properties and all stuff so lets see what OP has to say but thanks for the heads up...

Comment: Note from 2021: [browser support for `outline-offset` is quite good nowadays](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_outline-offset). Only IE11 is missing from the list.

Comment: @Calinou agreed, ie11 is of the past ;) CSS has become so much easier and powerfull nowdays

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up codes.

```css
.effect {
  outline: 4px solid #f99;

  /*
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  */
  /* (Optional) Size hack */
  display: table;
  padding: 25px 50px;

  position: relative;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    content: "";
    border: #9f9 4px solid;
  }
  &::before {
    border: #99f 8px solid;
  }
}
<div class="effect"></div>
```